# req.session don't set with post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am newby in node.js and I try to implement the simplest authorization in Express. I want to set `req.session.userId` to users id from database. I can get user id from database using simple form and post request, but I can't set `req.session.userId` . The most incomprehensible thing for me - why sometimes req.session is working and sometimes is not.
My code for explanation.
in **app.js**:

Configure segment:

```
app.use(express.session({secret: 'asdads', key: 'sid', cookie: { maxAge: 600000, httpOnly: false }}));
```

After that I handle POST request with:

```
app.post('/login', routes.authorize);
```

My routes.authorize:

```
exports.authorize = function(req, res){
    if(req.body){
        var login = req.body.login;
        var password = req.body.password;
  //gET USER FROM DATABASE
        db.getUser(login, password, function(err, results){
  //ensure that results is correct
            console.log(results);
            if(err){ res.send("User not found", 500); return;}
  //PLACE WITH BUG :)
            req.session.userId = results[0].id; 
        });
    }
    res.render('login', { title: 'Express!' });
}
```

I think I couldnt set req.session.userId in this place because I access here via POST. If I am right please help me to get access to `req.session` in this place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're immediately responding to the request before your `db.getUser()` completes. IIRC the Express session middleware saves session changes when the response is sent, so try something like this instead:

```
exports.authorize = function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body)
    return res.render('login', { title: 'Express!' });

  var login = req.body.login;
  var password = req.body.password;

  db.getUser(login, password, function(err, results) {
    if (err)
      return res.send("User not found", 500);
    req.session.userId = results[0].id;
    res.render('login', { title: 'Express!' });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought about sync/async execution, but I use node.js only second day and it quite difficult for me to catch bugs like this!

Comment: If you here... :)  How to do redirect after req.session.userId = results[0].id; ??

Comment: You can redirect with [`res.redirect()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.redirect).

Comment: Sure i tried it but it is not work if I use it after req.session.userId = results[0].id;

Comment: It works for me with [this simple demo](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1efa4157936445bc77ca).